# OAuth2 confusion, C#.Net

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to develop a web server application, running on an in-house server using C# and .net. The purpose of my application is to interface with Google Calendar, read events and then generate travel expense reports.

Basing my OAuth2 piece of the code from the example [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2/Default.aspx.cs?repo=samples&r=496199a24e7e91b47c8a6a27cb3660a710b1c634&spec=svn.samples.aa10ed7507ec1f7571900b19899687c9d4159ab1) I was able to come up with an application that works, mostly.

I say mostly because somewhere along the lines, confusion arises as to whether a user is logged in and or authenticated and which user is logged in.

For example:
If I launch Chrome and then access my application, all is well but if I then open another Browser (IE or FF), log in to a different Google account and then launch my application, the report it gives is that for the account that was/is logged into Google in Chrome? In the first browser (Chrome in this case) the URL contains the parameter ?code but the URL in the second browse does not and remains simply the URL to my application.

When I launch my application in the 2nd browser using a different Google account, it appears that Authentication is failing (Button text remains "Authenticate" BUT the line of code, see below, that fetches the calendar list is still executing and receiving a response after clicking on the "Authenticate" button, with the returned data being from the account that is/was logged in via the 1st browser.

```
CalendarList response = _service.CalendarList.List().Fetch();
```

I've tried without much success to find out why this is happening but it is starting to drive me crazy and so far limits the usefulness of my application.

Could the problem have something to do with the Session State information that is stored on our server? Is the OAuth2 code sample I am using out of date and if so where would I find a correct example?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How are you hosting your application? IIS Express? If so, when you launch the application a second time, are you sure IIS Express is restarting? You would have to have explicitly restarted it

Comment: We are hosting the application on IIS 7 running Windows Server 2008 Standard.

Comment: I've gone over the code from the original example and I noticed the following declarations: 
private static TasksService _service; // We don't need individual service instances for each client.
private static OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient> _authenticator;

My App uses CalendarService rather than TasksService but I left the types as static as in the example code. BUT when I remove static, my app seems to work correctly. Why in the example does is it infer that static is desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with user2367592, try test your application without a static service, and please let us know if it works.

Anyway, in version 1.5 (currently we use 1.3) we are going to get rid of DotNetOpenAuth and improve the whole OAuth2 experience, so - sorry for any inconvenient.

Comment: So far so good, without static service my application now appears to work correctly.